# Matching a regex in R while excluding punctuation

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have the following string:

```
x = "Mr. Mammon Moneybags is a British businessman, owner of Widgets Incorporated, the widget company, and owner of Supermarts chain store."
```

I want to pull out the company names. Obviously I want to start with a look-behind on `'owner of '`, then one or more word characters. I want the string to cut out on commas and full stops but not on dashes/apostrophes as they could be part of a company name. I also don't want to cut out on spaces because I want to capture both words in "Widgets Incorporated", but also only the word "Supermarts". But before we even get to capturing "Supermarts" by specifying capitalised words, I'm failing to end the capturing group on the comma following "Widgets Incorporated".

This regex captures only half of the first group, but correctly captures the second group.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, '(?<=owner of )(\w+(?!,))')
[1,] 'Widgets' [2,] 'Supermarts'
```

This only partially captures the first group, and over-shoots in the second group.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, '(?<=owner of )(\w+\s\w+)(?!,)')
[1,] 'Widgets Incorporate' [2,] 'Supermarts chain'
```

I was certain one of these would at least capture the first group. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `(?<=owner of )[^,.]+`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cdC5lw/1).

Comment: Thank you this is much more parsimonious than I expected it to end up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the restriction that each word must be capitalized, you could use,

```
str_extract_all(x, '(?<=owner of\\W)([A-Z]\\w+(\\s+[A-Z]\\w+)*)')
[[1]]
[1] "Widgets Incorporated" "Supermarts"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```r
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=owner of )[^,.]+")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cdC5lw/1).

**Details**:

- `(?<=owner of )`  - a location immediately preceded with `owner of` + space
- `[^,.]+` - one or more chars other than `.` and `,`.